# Character encoding issue with Mulesoft IBM MQ Connector

Tags: mule, ibm-mq, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

Problem Description:

- We are trying to transfer a zip file to a destination coming from an IBM MQ queue.
- The Mulesoft flow has an IBM MQ 'On New Message' connector as a source.
- Whenever there is a new message in the IBM MQ queue, the connector picks that up and the 'Write' connector is writing that into the local file system (in our original scenario we are using an SFTP connector to send the file to an SFTP server. However, for simplicity here we are just using the Write connector to write into our local file system to mimic the process of writing into the SFTP server file system).
- The problem we are having is the zip file is getting corrupted when the Mule flow writes that in the file system.
- I believe the reason behind that is the connector is trying to convert the character encoding, whereas we need a binary transfer of the data.
- Please advise how we can configure the IBM MQ connector so that it transfers the data as binary without enforcing any character encoding.

The connector version we're currently leveraging is - **1.6.7** and we've tried upgrading its version as well but it didn't help either.

Any leads on the above problem statement would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the MQMD.Format set to?

Comment: You did a good job of describing the issue however you should also provide the configurations and flows of your implementation. Help others to understand and reproduce the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more tips and detailed instructions on how to ask.